# Running geddyjs on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, geddy

I'm wanting to start using the Geddy js framework for node and have followed the installation instructions provided in their tutorial but have not been able to get it to run.
I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and have version 0.10.15 of NodeJS installed and running, NPM 1.2.18, and Jake 0.6.10. There were no errors returned when NPM installed geddy.

Running geddy from a terminal returns nothing, no errors, no 'command not found' just returns the command prompt...

Have I missed something obvious? I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu and very new to Node so I apologise if this is a newbie issue.

cheers :)

Comment: Can you let us know what geddy command you are running in particular?

Comment: I was trying the 'geddy gen app to_do' command as shown in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed geddy globally? If not it can be installed by using below command:

```
npm install -g geddy
```

**Installation Instructions**: http://geddyjs.org/tutorial